# Open source web conferencing system using java / JMF

Tags: java, audio, jmf, conferencing

Is there any Open source web conferencing solutions in Java, which could support features like a shared whiteboard, presentations, audio, video, Record / play back presentations etc? I am looking at some thing like WebEx, but also have a whiteboard to draw/share presentations.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is old, however, I need to clarify that in BigBlueButton yes we use Java in the server side, you can check the code in the github repo:

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton

In the the client side is done with flex, and for the desktop sharing is done with a java applet...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know **OpenMeetings**?

- http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/

It uses Java but not solely. Other languages like Flash are also used.

The only alternative I know is **BigBlueButton** (GPL version available).

But it does not use Java at all..

- Web page: http://bigbluebutton.org/
- Google project page: http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/

Comment: BigBlueButton is implemented in Java.